# How to union between two datasets with a variable number of fields, using SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two query results from different tables like below.

> ID　　F1　　F2　　F3　　　　　　ID　　F3　　F4　　F5
>   S1　 d11　　d12 　d13 　　　　　S2　　d23 　d24　 d25
>   S2　 d21　　d22 　d23 　　　　　S3　　d33 　d34　 d35
>   S3　 d31　　d32 　d33 　　　　　S4　　d43 　d44　 d45

ID and F# are field names, the others are values. I want to get a new result in a similar form to the following from the results above.

> ID　　F1　　F2　　F3　　F4　　F5
>   S1　 d11　　d12 　d13
>   S2　 d21　　d22 　d23
>   S2　　　　　　　　d23　 d24　　d25
>   S3　 d31　　d32 　d33
>   S3　　　　　　　　d33　 d34　　d35
>   S4　　　　　　　　d43　 d44　　d45

Is this possible in SQL? I'm programming in VBA with ADO. I've never done such a task before.

Note that the fields of the first two tables are dynamic. I can't predict how many there are or what they are.

Comment: Oh no. It seems people don't open this thread any more. The problem is still there. :(

Comment: be patient, it's just been an hour. Also: if you don't get the answers you hope for, try to improve the question by explaining more clearly what you need. This might help anyone (yourself or others) to find a solution.

Answer (score 7):

```
select ID, F1, F2, F3, NULL as F4, NULL as F5
from Table1
union all
select ID, NULL as F1, NULL as F2, F3, F4, F5
from Table2
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not so easy. The first two tables are query results from Excel tables which grow with time, and the query strings to get them are built programmingly. I can't predict how many fields there will be. There can be F6, F7, ... They are dynamic.

Comment: @phoenies: when you don't know the schema before-hand, then SQL is pretty much the wrong language to use. *Or* you will have to write code that **generates** the SQL according to some mechanism.

Comment: Extend the already programatically built query string to add the dummy columns. Then you will find that the _real_ problem here is no program can predict how any new fields will map. If you get two new fields in each source, are they meant to be the same column or not? You don't know without some human analysis to give you the answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do a full outer join on two sub-queries that generate a fake join key that is never equal.  This way you could use a select * to get any columns that exist in the two tables.

```
select * from 
(select 1 as MY_ID, Table1.* from Table1) AS A
FULL OUTER JOIN
(select 2 as MY_ID, Table2.* from Table2) AS B
ON A.MY_ID = B.MY_ID
```